# HTTP Request based Android Chat

Tags: java, php, android, json

What's the principle?

My vision: Users will loads a plain lightweight page which will be empty as long as there's no new messages every 2-3 seconds. When user receives a message the page will show new messages. Since page is opened once and data (JSON) is downloaded, parsed, added to chat screen and marked as read it will show an empty page again as long as there's no new messages.

Is that correct? I'm worried about battery usage. I haven't tested it yet to see the battery usage, but what do you guys say about it? So basically is there a better way to do it? I want to know principle/working method how should I make it to achieve a low battery usage?

Comment: Can you check with AngularJS or ReactJS. It has so many solutions for chatting apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow two methods to make it work efficiently.

1. One is create the server with the Web socket connection and establish the Web socket connection to the server from the android as it is full duplex over the HTTP and then perform the sending and receiving of data.
2. Other is using the push notification concept in the android just send the push notification from the server to the device when any message comes, rather than listening to the server ever 3 sec. While replying back to the contact use the wss(Web-socket connection) established and perform the chat. So that you can disconnect the wss once if the user is idle and can listen to the messages on push notification Chanel.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will mark it as solution ASAP since it answers to my question completely.